# How can child process tell its parent to create a new child?

Tags: c++, c, fork, child-process

Dears,

I'm writing a network server application using C++.

When starts it creates a listener socket and an user-defined number of child processes (workers), each one monitoring the listener (using kqueue, epoll, etc.) for new client connections, `accept()`'ing them and creating a thread to deal with response processing. Once a worker child process answers a user-defined number of client requests, it must tell parent process to create a new child process, wait until all threads are done and then exit.

My question is: if I have a function (`create_child()`) in my parent that creates a child process, can I just call it from within child and will get a new child of parent process (desired result), or will it create a child of child? Ex. (pseudo-code):

```
void create_child() {
    //create child process
}

int main()
{
    //do things

    if(fork() == 0) {
        //do things

        create_child(); //is result a child of parent or child of child?
    }
}
```

I prefer to not use pipes, I want to avoid its overhead, but please tell me if it's the only solution. I currently have no Linux system here to write a simple program and test what happens, but in my searches I read somewhere that it will create a child of child process. So, **how to create a child of parent from within another child**?

I'm sorry if it become hard to understand, I was a bit sleepy when writing this question. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If fork() has returned 0, you're already in a child process when you get to your create_child function.  This process is a child of the process that called fork.  The original parent process has no special meaning, and is not tracked by fork.

Comment: What else will the parent process be doing? Why not have the parent process watch for the termination of the child, and create a new child to replace it?

Comment: @Donnie, I know it. What I want is some way to, from within child (after fork() == 0), tell parent to create a new child.

Comment: @Beta new child must be created when worker's answered requests count reach user-defined value. Worker will not exit when this happens, it will wait somethings get done first, but new worker must be already there before that. I'll add some more details regarding this in question.

Comment: What you want is called _interprocess communication_.

Comment: You need to use IPC of some sort to ask the parent to fork for you.  If pipes are too heavy and you don't need a lot of communication there are other IPC mechanisms avialable  (a semaphore, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you do `fork`s, and want communication between parent & child processes (or between processes in general, come to think of it), you can use [pipe](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    main()
    {
            int     fd[2];
            pid_t   childpid;

            pipe(fd);

            if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
            {
                    perror("fork");
                    exit(1);
            }
            .
            .
    }
```

The child and parent can read and write using the (surprise!) `read` and `write` system calls, using the `fd`s. (If the communication should be one way, then some fo the `fd`s should be closed, incidentally.)

Once you have communication, you can devise whatever protocol you want for the child to communicate with the parent, including for spanning other processes.

Comment: It seems to solve my problem, but I want to avoid pipes to get rid of additional overhead and work for the OS (will need kqueue/epoll monitoring pipe, I read something about system needing to keep pipes synchronism...) as performance is a critical point for this application...

Comment: I think you'll be surprised. Profile to see if the addition of a pipe call, to actually launching a new process - actually makes a difference. I am willing to bet you a cup of coffee (don't know how to do the logistics on that, though) - that it won't. :-) Don't forget - premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the 1st question : If you fork from a child, then the child has a child. Your initial parent process is grand parent of that last process.

What's more interresting is that if the first child terminates, while the second child is still running -- which is what would happen in your current design -- the second child becomes orphan and is attached to init. No process is allowed to have no parent. The initial parent process cannot monitor this abbandonned grand child that's just been adopted by init.

answer to 2nd question : you can't.

You should probably monitor children from within parent. With your current design, what if a child dies before it can tell parent to replace it ? or before it replaces itself ?

this could be a starting point :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
  create_process();
for(;;) {
  int status;
  wait( &status );
  create_process();
}
```

Comment: Monitor children (for their exit) from within parent process doesn't solve entire problem, as child is going to tell parent to create a new child even before it exits. Thank you anyway, your answer reminded me of add a monitoring for number of workers `accept()`'ing requests, as some can unexpectedly exits because of uncaught exception or something else before telling parent to replace it.